# Which algorithm should I use to find how similar data points are?

Tags: clustering, algorithms

I am working with a dataset where each record is a certain type of trip. For example, one record would have the data points:

- number of days of trip
- day the trip started
- where the trip started
- how many hours the trip was
- how many times stops occurred on each trip

What I'm trying to approximate is how similar these trips actually are if they are similar. Or how different are they? Ideally, I can come up with 5 features of the dataset that each instance in the original dataframe all have in common.

I assume that some sort of clustering method should be used, but I am new to clustering. If I could get pointed in any direction to understand which algorithm I should be investigating, that would be much appreciated!!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming all the 5 features are numerical, clustering algorithm could be deployed.
Apart from that, cosine similarity between the individual vectors, where each vector would represent a trip.